# Loop and Add Range in a place holder

Tags: vba, excel

[image: Add Range in a place holder]

Hello,

First of all, thanks for everyone who's helped me with my previous concern. I have another loop issue though. What I'm trying to do is store a certain range on a place holder and use for Charts. My code loops through column A to check cells that contain `Product/URL` and if found, will offset to the next column and will store the range highlighted on a place holder.

What I was able to do so far is to just select the cell with content in-line with cell with `Product/URL`. Here's my code so far.

```
Dim ProdCell as Range

For Each ProdCell in [A:A].SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    If Not IsEmpty(Prodcell) and Prodcell.Cells.Value = [A1] Then
        ProdCell.Offset(0,1).Cells.End(xlToRight).Select
    End if
Next ProdCell
```

I believe that if I can find a way to highlight the range using VBA coding, I will be able to loop through it. Please help.

Comment: So you want to select 6 rows and all columns to the left of the cell in column A? Is it always six rows?

Comment: How do you define the place holder? What we need to understand is what will be placed in the found range where `Product/URL` is found.

Comment: @SJR- No not really, new columns will be added for the dates every week.

Comment: @L42 - Product/URL is just the marker where the range selection will offset. In the image, Product/URL in A1 is where the selection offset to the right and select Range between KW up the last Date but not including the Row for the next Product/URL in A7.